# Merge and find the diff in df

Tags: python, pandas

Compare if A column is present in C, if not the type Vnot found. if present then compare B and D. if not present type T not found else NA.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'A': [1, 2, 3],
         'B': ['p', 's', 'r']}

data2 = {'C': ['3', '2', '5'],
         'D': ['p', 'r', 'q']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Function to compare and generate new column
def compare_columns(row):
    if row['A'] in df2['C'].astype(int).values:
        idx = df2[df2['C'].astype(int) == row['A']].index[0]
        if row['B'] == df2.loc[idx, 'D']:
            return 'NA'
        else:
            return 'T Not Found'
    else:
        return 'V Not Found'

# Apply the function to generate the new column 'E'
df1['E'] = df1.apply(compare_columns, axis=1)
df1.loc[df1['E'] == 'V Not Found', 'E'] = 'V not found'
df1.loc[df1['E'] == 'T Not Found', 'E'] = 'T Not Found'
df1.loc[df1['E'] == 'NA', 'E'] = 'NA'

print(df1)
```

expected output:

```
`   A  B            E
0  1  p  V not found
1  2  s  T Not Found
2  3  r  NA
```

`
i want the expected output as given above but i get

```
`   A  B            E
0  1  p  V not found
1  2  s  T Not Found
2  3  r  T Not Found`
```

Comment: Why are you using a different strategy to search based on "column A" and "column B"?

Comment: i am not doing that in this code. if i am , then can you please help it rectify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you can use essentially the same code to test if "A" in "C" and if "B" in "D"

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': ['p', 's', 'r']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'C': ['3', '2', '5'],
    'D': ['p', 'r', 'q']
})

def compare_columns(row):
    if row['A'] not in df2['C'].astype(int).values:
        return 'V Not Found'
    
    if row['B'] not in df2['D'].astype(str).values:
        return 'T Not Found'

    return 'NA'

df1['E'] = df1.apply(compare_columns, axis=1)

print(df1)
```

That should give you:

```
   A  B            E
0  1  p  V Not Found
1  2  s  T Not Found
2  3  r           NA
```

Comment: thanks much. this works for mock data set. let me try for the huge data set and get back to you on the result set soon.

Comment: This will be slow for big data set due to `apply`. Left merge and condition on A,B would be the way to go. Or just use `.isin` function.

Comment: @JonSG, i have asked somewhat similar question, can you please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76923086/compare-2-df-by-merging-two-columns

Comment: is it possible to add one more condition if it has na then compare with one more df and give more appropriate reason by saying duplicstate row found?

Comment: sure. If you add the new data to your question I will update the answer

Comment: @JonSG, i am gettingthis error     f"Wrong number of items passed {len(values)}, "
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1.. any idea

Answer (score 1):

Use the vectorized `.isin` function with `np.select` is better:

```
df1['E'] = np.select((~df1['A'].isin(df2['C'].astype(int)), ~df1['B'].isin(df2['D'])),
                     ('V not found', 'T not found'), pd.NA
                    )
```

Output:

```
   A  B            E
0  1  p  V not found
1  2  s  T not found
2  3  r         <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach using merges to test if A in C and B and D individually.

1. Create AC which checks for A in C
2. Create BD which checks for B in D
3. Merge AC and BD which creates a table that shows if A is in C and if B is in D
4. Look at whether C or D column is null to indicate non-matches and create the appropriate labeling.

```
data1 = {"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": ["p", "s", "r"]}

data2 = {"C": ["3", "2", "5"], "D": ["p", "r", "q"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df2["C"] = df2["C"].astype(int)

AC = df1.merge(df2, how="left", left_on="A", right_on="C")[["A", "B", "C"]]
BD = df1.merge(df2, how="left", left_on="B", right_on="D")[["B", "D"]]

E = AC.merge(BD)

E.loc[E.C.isnull(), "E"] = "V Not Found"
E.loc[~E.C.isnull() & E.D.isnull(), "E"] = "T Not Found"
E.loc[~E.C.isnull() & ~E.D.isnull(), "E"] = "NA"

E = E[["A", "B", "E"]]
```