# Compare 2 df by merging two columns

Tags: python

I have below dfs. Df1 is the list and df2 is the master list. df1's viewname should be compared with df2's viewname. if not present, type view not found. if its present,then compare df1 coulmn name with df2s viewnames column name.
it should be combination of df2's viewname and colname for searching.

[image]

```
    col_desc_diff_df = cd_diff[cd_diff['_merge'] == 'left_only'][['View Name', 'Column Name', 'Column Description']]
    
    selected_cols_df = view_col_desc_df[['View Name','Column Name']]
    selected_cols_df1 =  selected_cols_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['View Name','Column Name'])

    def compare_columns_cd(row):
        if row['View Name'] not in selected_cols_df1['View Name'].astype(str).values:
            return 'View Not Found'        
        if row['Column Name'] not in selected_cols_df1['Column Name'].astype(str).values:
            return 'Column Not Found'
        return 'NA'
    col_desc_diff_df['Reason for Diff'] = col_desc_diff_df.apply(compare_columns_cd, axis=1)
```

```
Additional Request: if df2 and df1 had aa a1 def , then df1's aa a1 def should have reason as duplicate row. is it possible to acheive?
```

Comment: Is this data in csv files by chance, creating a lookup with a dictionary rather than df2 would be simple

Comment: no its a data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if it was me, I would create a distinct lookup structure out of `df2` then use it to set a column on `df1`. Potentially something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'View_Name': ["aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", "dd"],
    'Col_Name': ["a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "b3"]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'View_Name': ["aa", "aa", "bb", "cc"],
    'Col_Name': ["a1", "c1", "b2", "b3"],
})

## ----------------
## build a lookup
## ----------------
lookup = {}
for t in df2.itertuples():
    lookup.setdefault(t[1], set()).add(t[2])
## ----------------

def get_reason(row):
    View_Name = row["View_Name"]
    if View_Name not in lookup:
        return "View Not Found"
    
    Col_Name = row["Col_Name"]
    if Col_Name not in lookup[View_Name]:
        return "Column Not Found"
    
    return "matched"

df1["Reason"] = df1.apply(get_reason, axis=1)

print(df1)
```

That should give you:

```
  View_Name Col_Name            Reason
0        aa       a1           matched
1        aa       a2  Column Not Found
2        bb       b1  Column Not Found
3        bb       b2           matched
4        dd       b3    View Not Found
```

Comment: is it possible to include NA if view and column both matched ?

Comment: Just change `return "matched"` to `return "NA"`

Comment: you mind helping for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76942390/compare-2-nested-df-using-python ? this is extended version of this question

Comment: Can you please help me by answering  myother questions ? it will be of great help. pls

Comment: Hi, that question seem to already have an answer. Is it not working for you?

Comment: i have added one more df to get one more condition