# Compare 2 nested DF using Python

Tags: python

```
I/P:
    data = {'Viewname': ['V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V2', 'V3'],
    'Column Name': ['c1', 'c1', 'C7', 'C4', 'C5'],
    'Col Desc': ['abc', 'def', 'dfg', 'tyh', 'gth']}

    master = {'Viewname2': ['V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V2'],
    'Column Name2': ['c1', 'c1', 'C2', 'C4'],
    'Col Desc2': ['abc', 'def', 'dfg', 'tyh']}


Expected O/P:
    data = {'Viewname': ['V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V2', 'V3'],
    'Column Name': ['c1', 'c1', 'C7', 'C4', 'C5'],
    'Col Desc': ['abc', 'def', 'dfg', 'tyh', 'gth'],
    'Reason for diff': ['Duplicate Row', 'Matched', 'Col not found', 'Matched', 'View Not Found']}

    master = {'Viewname2': ['V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V2'],
    'Column Name2': ['c1', 'c1', 'C2', 'C4'],
    'Col Desc2': ['abc', 'def', 'dfg', 'tyh']}
```

`
This is how my df s look like.
[image]

**Logic of `Reason for diff` column:**

`df2` is the input sheet and `df1` is the validation report. for `v1,c1` the data for desc gets updated, again if it finds the same combination it will update the `def`, so I want all the previous ( except the last) occurrences as duplicate rows. if there is one view and column in both the dfs then it is matched.
1st preference, is if viewname is not found, then if view is present, then check for column.

Comment: you can describe it about more detail

Comment: What is the difference between `Duplicate Row` and `Matched`?

Comment: df2 is the input sheet and df1 is the validation report.
for v1,c1 the data for desc gets updated, again if it finds same combiation it will update the def , so i want all the previous ( except the last) ocureneces as duplicate row..
if there is one view and column in both the dfs then it is matched

Comment: @rose For `v3, c5`, both view and col are not found, why you selected only `view not found`?

Comment: apologies for all the confusion. have created a new question with full details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76943582/compare-multiple-dfs-to-achieve-final-df

Comment: i understand, but while doing so it gives me You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is not the answer, but helpful to OP, to find the solution.

OP's logic is not clear, for some conditions like,  `v3, c5`, both view and col are not found, but not sure why OP selected only `View not found`

```
import pandas as pd

master = {'Viewname2': ['V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V2'],
'Column Name2': ['c1', 'c1', 'C2', 'C4'],
'Col Desc2': ['abc', 'def', 'dfg', 'tyh']}

data = {'Viewname': ['V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V2', 'V3'],
'Column Name': ['c1', 'c1', 'C7', 'C4', 'C5'],
'Col Desc': ['abc', 'def', 'dfg', 'tyh', 'gth']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(master)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

merged_df = pd.merge(df2, df1, 
                     left_on=['Viewname', 'Column Name', 'Col Desc'], 
                     right_on=['Viewname2', 'Column Name2', 'Col Desc2'], 
                     how='left')

# Initialize the 'Reason for diff' column
merged_df['Reason for diff'] = ''

# Mark 'Matched' rows
matched_rows = merged_df['Viewname2'].notna() & merged_df['Column Name2'].notna()
merged_df.loc[matched_rows, 'Reason for diff'] = 'Matched'

# Mark 'Duplicate Row' rows
merged_df.loc[:, 'Reason for diff'] = np.where(merged_df.groupby(by=['Viewname', 'Column Name']).cumcount(ascending=False).add(1) > 1,
         'Duplicate Row', 'Matched')

#  Mark 'View Not Found' rows
view_not_found_rows = merged_df['Viewname2'].isna() 
merged_df.loc[view_not_found_rows, 'Reason for diff'] = 'View Not Found'

# Mark 'Col not found' rows
col_not_found_rows = merged_df['Column Name2'].isna()
merged_df.loc[col_not_found_rows, 'Reason for diff'] = 'Col not found'


# Reorder the columns
reordered_columns = ['Viewname', 'Column Name', 'Col Desc', 'Reason for diff']
merged_df = merged_df[reordered_columns]
```

---

```
print(merged_df)

  Viewname Column Name Col Desc Reason for diff
0       V1          c1      abc   Duplicate Row
1       V1          c1      def         Matched
2       V2          C7      dfg   Col not found
3       V2          C4      tyh         Matched
4       V3          C5      gth   Col not found
```

Comment: Can you please help with my other questions

Answer (score 0):

you question should include more details, In my understanding, this is the codes I write.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Viewname': ['V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V2', 'V3'], 'Column Name': ['c1', 'c1', 'C7', 'C4', 'C5'], 'Col Desc': ['abc', 'def', 'dfg', 'tyh', 'gth'], 'Reason for diff': ['Duplicate Row', 'Matched', 'Col not found', 'Matched', 'View Not Found']}
master = {'Viewname': ['V1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V2'], 'Column Name': ['c1', 'c1', 'C2', 'C4'], 'Col Desc': ['abc', 'def', 'dfg', 'tyh']}

df0 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(master)

df = pd.merge(df0, df1, how='outer', on=['Viewname', 'Column Name', 'Col Desc'])

df
```

[image]

Comment: `Reason for diff` column is a derived column based on OP's mentioned conditions.

Comment: @jiu_zou: this is not expected.